# Failing to understand the value of asynchronous functions specially from a library

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous

I am implementing an asynchronous function from a library but now I am doubting if the 'asynchronous' nature if it is useful at all. Here is prototype of the function.

```
bool DoSomething(HANDLE wait)
```

How does the client knows the work is complete? The library function signals the `wait` handle passed to it. Now all this works fine but I am wondering that client application will still want to wait on the function to process/display the results. This in return means they should be calling it in a secondary thread (you don't want to wait your primary GUI thread). Doesn't this mute the whole purpose of async call in the first place when it is to be called in secondary thread anyways?

The closest thing I can think of is windows' `ReadFile()` which can run asynchronously but then we (often) need to wait for it `GetOverlappedResult()`. The scenario is similar. The async function is implemented itself in an internal thread (at least mine) so it only adds a n extra thread. I am failing to see motivation of providing an sync thread from library? Am I missing something? In almost all cases, the client would want to wait on it so why not run in the same thread afterall?

Comment: "In *almost* all cases" - perhaps because of that *almost*?

Comment: What if you have to call DoSomething many times ? What is the most effective solution ? Calling it, then waiting for completion, then repeat ? Or maybe calling a few instances in a batch, wait for completion for the whole batch, and repeat ?

Comment: @SirDarius Yes that seems to be the first valid advantage I have seen. One thread can issue multiple async calls and than wait on all the handles at once with `WaitForMultiple`objects. That said this scenario would be a rare need and I certainly don't need it. So far I am dropping async support from my functions.

Comment: Yes, this scenario is common for server software that has to perform a lot of network or file I/O in parallel, and blocking would cause the program to use too many threads. Asynchronous APIs leverage low-level mechanisms that make this use-case much cheaper in terms of necessary resources. In your case, I believe this is too much complexity for no apparent immediate benefit.

Comment: I don't know about low level mechanism, maybe the kernal APIs implements them that way but I have implemented mine using internal thread so in my case the threads are the same.

Answer (score -1):

If you doubt that asynchronous is useful, you should not use asynchronous functions.

There a several models for asynchronous programming. These include:
1. Queueing
2. Threading
3. Interrupt
Asynchronous programming allows your application to do one thing while waiting on another. For example, your application can continuously update the screen while doing interaction with the user at the same time.

The way the client knows the work is complete is through synchronization methods. The synchronization methods available depend upon the asynchronous model being used.

Comment: queueing/mailbox also requires a thread to wait on them which would most likely not be primary thread. Can you give an prototype of function that will not require a secondary thread please?

Comment: I was referring to function prototype but for function, it can do anything for illustration. For example a simple `for` loop from 1 to 10 with 1 sec sleep function in it so it will 10 seconds to complete. At the end it post time to the caller when the function was completed.

Comment: My particularly model is async function doesn't return any data but it only notifies the client that it is complete. The client than sends a secondary call to getch the data. That call is plain.